# label and scroll view

Tags: iphone, ipad

HI FRIENDS..
 I use a scroll view and a label now i want that when i scroll that , label also scroll with that and set to next location , i set paging enable = YES , so i want that there are 5 images and when i did scrolling the label i set is also move and show in other position.

thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: You may need to reword your question better, this sorta doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i m sorry for my english friend , i not know much about that language and no need to learn , if you understand what i m trying to say please post your answer , do not comment for just timepass

Comment: Trying to help you but I don't understand your question .. maybe there is a similar site in your language since this one is mostly in English.

Comment: hope this makes you clear that i want to move that label over scroll view

Comment: @vijay my friend can you please tell me what you want. I mean your requirement. From looking at your question its really hard to tell what your question is. Also dont abuse other developers here.

Comment: @robin: Agree with you, Plz tell me who have voted me down and why ?

Comment: sorry @jhaliya i dont know that

Comment: hmm.. sry but for that. i need to reset the frame of the label , suppose my next image x-coordinates are (360,20,120,100) ok , now when i do scrolling it go to this images i want that label also move to this place

Comment: @vijay: If you want you can use google translater..

Comment: @vijay can you tell me one thing, do you have a scrollview as your view controllers view or did you add a uiscrollview on top of a normal uiview

Comment: i add a scroll view using [self.view addsubview:scroollview];

Answer (score 1):

To scroll a UILabel (or anything for that matter) WITH a UIScrollView, simply add the label to the UIScrollView.

You can easily do this in Interface Builder by the obvious methods.

You can also do this programmatically by utilizing the `addSubview:` method.

Comment: i already add that label to that scroll but i want to move the frame of the label

Comment: If you added the label to the scrollview, then it should automatically scroll with your UIScrollView .. If it doesn;t scroll along, then you didnt do it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing you change frame of label when you scroll in delegate method of scrollview or you can also make 5 same label in all 5 pages.
Good Luck

Comment: no i already told you that i want to move one label across the scroll no need to make 5 different label.

Comment: ok then i already give you alternate option that you can set frame of your label in content view of scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have added a scrollview on top of a uiview you can add that label on the view and then bring it to front. then you dont have to worry about changing frame of the uilabel as it will be always on top of the scrollview and at the same position and also you can change the text of that label when the user scrolls in pagecontrol value changed method.

Comment: i told you already friend that i want to move that label , so not want to add it on view it make it static and fixed it in one place, i want to add that label in a scroll view so when i do scrolling that label alos move